# Parsing XML excluding elements

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xelement

I'm trying to parse a xml file, which isn't the problem. But my xml file has multiple `<name>` tags. One is for a song, and the other one is for an artist. I want to exclude the artist name tag, but I can't figure out how.

Here's my code so far:

```
        string xmlString;
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            xmlString = wc.DownloadString(@"http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getInfo&album=awake&artist=Dream%20Theater&api_key=b5cbf8dcef4c6acfc5698f8709841949");
        }
        List<XElement> alleElements = new List<XElement>();
        XDocument myXMLDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        List<XElement> trackNames = myXMLDoc.Descendants("album")
                           .Elements("tracks")
                           .Elements("name")
                           .ToList();


        foreach (XElement el in trackNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("-----End-----");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I tried using `.Elements("name");` instead of Descendants, but that returns nothing at all.

Here's a small part of my xml file:

```
<track rank="1">
    <name>6:00</name>
    <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Dream+Theater/_/6:00</url>
    <duration>331</duration>
    <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
    <artist>
        <name>Dream Theater</name>
        <mbid>28503ab7-8bf2-4666-a7bd-2644bfc7cb1d</mbid>
        <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Dream+Theater</url>
    </artist>
</track>
```

Is there a way to exclude the `<name>` tag inside the `<artist>` tag.

If I'm not clear enough, please let me know and I'll explain it more!

Comment: Using `Elements("name")` should be absolutely fine. If it isn't, please show a short but *complete* example (a complete XML document and a complete console app) showing it not working.

Comment: This still isn't a complete program. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/run. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'll do that next time. Your answer worked though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to use `Elements` instead of `Descendants`, but at the right point - it's not clear where you tried using it. I'd also recommend using `ToList` to make things simpler. Given the sample in the [documentation](http://www.last.fm/api/show/album.getInfo), it looks like this would work and be clearer in terms of where we expect there to be multiple elements:

```
List<XElement> trackNames = doc.Root
                               .Element("tracks")
                               .Elements("track")
                               .Elements("name")
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried it, and I got this result: http://imgur.com/3QdFctc, Also this is my XML file: http://imgur.com/VzJhax0

Comment: @Bas: Screenshots are a very hard to use way of sharing your problem. Please update your question with a short but complete example of code, XML and results *as text*. Note that the ancestor elements of the XML could be very important, due to namespace defaulting.

Comment: @Bas: See my edit - we were looking for name directly in `tracks`, not `track`...

Comment: @Bas: No, you still haven't edited the question. And it would be more useful to include a small but complete sample of the XML *in the question*. But I *have* edited the answer, so you should be able to use that.

Comment: Your answer worked! I'm terribly sorry for being unclear, I'll keep everything you said in mind for future question. Thanks a million for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try excluding with a condition, like `myXMLDoc. ... .Descendants("name").Where(x => x.Parent.Name != "artist").`